# How to set state after get value from function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

May i know how to set state value after get value from function?

```
const getValueFunction = () => {
    dispatch(fetchData(setData, 1, pages.current, rowsNumber));
  }

useEffect(() => {
    pages.current = 1;
    getValueFunction();
    const obj = data.reduce((r, { setCode }) => {
      const l = setCode[0];
      if (!r[l]) r[l] = [setCode];
      else r[l].push(setCode);
      return r;
    }, {});

    const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    
    setOrderList(sorted);
    
    console.log("69========"+JSON.stringify(orderList));

  }, []);
```

When I tried to print out "orderList" for first load, it will return empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
    pages.current = 1;
    getValueFunction();
    const obj = data.reduce((r, { setCode }) => {
      const l = setCode[0];
      if (!r[l]) r[l] = [setCode];
      else r[l].push(setCode);
      return r;
    }, {});

    const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    
    setOrderList(sorted);
    
    console.log("69========"+JSON.stringify(orderList));

  }, [orderList]);
```

If I put orderlist in [], then it will keep loading non stop.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Is `[data, setData]` the result of a `useState` call?

Comment: @Caleth yup, correct, is useState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split up the effect that wants to run once, fetching the initial data, from the effect that wants to run each time `data` changes. I'm assuming that nothing else is setting `orderList`. If that's not the case [@ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77329061/2610810) suits better

```
const getValueFunction = () => {
    dispatch(fetchData(setData, 1, pages.current, rowsNumber));
}

useEffect(() => {
    pages.current = 1;
    getValueFunction();
}, []);

const orderList = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return [];

    const obj = data.reduce((r, { setCode }) => {
      const l = setCode[0];
      if (!r[l]) r[l] = [setCode];
      else r[l].push(setCode);
      return r;
    }, {});

    return Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));
}, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question and assuming that the variable **data** is the data that is populated through fetchData(), the solution is to synchronise your calculation based on data:

```js
const getValueFunction = () => {
    dispatch(fetchData(setData, 1, pages.current, rowsNumber));
}

useEffect(() => {
    pages.current = 1;
    getValueFunction();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    // Assuming data can be null or an array
    if (!data || !data?.length) {
      return;
    }

    const obj = data.reduce((r, { setCode }) => {
      const l = setCode[0];
      if (!r[l]) r[l] = [setCode];
      else r[l].push(setCode);
      return r;
    }, {});

    const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));
    
    setOrderList(sorted);
}, [data]);
```